# How to insert a picture from an existing table with file path and desired placement

Tags: excel, image, dynamic, resize

I'm trying to create the following template:

The user creates a table in a "Data Entry" worksheet that lists the following:

1. File path ie: P:\Phone Camera Dump\20121224_111617.jpg
2. Range where the picture is to be placed in the "PICS" worksheet.

[image: (See Image)]

Once the list is finalized, the user executes and images are placed within the ranges specified on the "PICS" worksheet and dynamically re-sized.

Presently the range has a set width of 624px and a height of 374px, but ideally, I would like the image to resize (aspect ratio not locked) dynamically in the width and height change.

I've used the following code as a base but am struggling with how to incorporate the cell ranges instead of the static row updates:

```
Sub InsertSeveralImages()

Dim pic_Path As String 'File path of the picture
Dim cl As Range, Rng As Range
Dim WS_Templte As Worksheet

Set WS_Templte = Worksheets("PICS")
Set Rng = Worksheets("Data Entry").Range("C13:C42")

pastingRow = 2

For Each cl In Rng

    pic_Path = cl.Value
    Set InsertingPicture = WS_Templte.Pictures.Insert(pic_Path)
   
    'Setting of the picture
    With InsertingPicture
        .ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
        .Height = 100
        .Top = WS_Templte.Rows(pastingRow).Top
        .Left = WS_Templte.Columns(3).Left
    End With
   
    pastingRow = pastingRow + 5
         
Next cl
       
Set myPicture = Nothing

WS_Templte.Activate

End Sub
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Here is the code in case anyone wants to use it:

Public Sub InsertPictures()

Dim vntFilePath As Variant
Dim rngFilePath As Range
Dim vntPastePath As Variant
Dim rngPastePath As Range
Dim lngCounter As Long
Dim pic As Picture
Set WS_Templte = Worksheets("PICS")

On Error GoTo ErrHandler
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PICS") '<-- Change sheet name accordingly

' Set first cell containing a row number
Set rngFilePath = .Range("BJ7")
vntFilePath = rngFilePath.Value

' Set first cell containing a paste range
Set rngPastePath = .Range("BK7")
vntPastePath = rngPastePath.Value

```
Do Until IsEmpty(vntFilePath)

  If Dir(vntFilePath) = "" Then vntFilePath = strNOT_FOUND_PATH
  Set pic = .Pictures.Insert(vntFilePath)
  lngCounter = lngCounter + 1
           
  With pic
    
    .ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
    
    If .ShapeRange.Rotation = 90! Or .ShapeRange.Rotation = 270! Then
        .Height = Application.CentimetersToPoints(16.3)
        .Width = Application.CentimetersToPoints(10.03)
        .Top = WS_Templte.Rows(rngPastePath).Top - (.Height - .Width) / 2#
        .Left = WS_Templte.Columns(4).Left + (.Height - .Width) / 2#
    Else
        .Width = Application.CentimetersToPoints(10.03)
        .Height = Application.CentimetersToPoints(16.3)
        .Top = WS_Templte.Rows(rngPastePath).Top
        .Left = WS_Templte.Columns(4).Left
   End If
   
  End With
        
  Set rngFilePath = rngFilePath.Offset(1)
  vntFilePath = rngFilePath.Value
  Set rngPastePath = rngPastePath.Offset(1)
  vntPastePath = rngPastePath.Value

Loop
```

End With

MsgBox lngCounter & " pictures were inserted.", vbInformation

ExitProc:
Set rngFilePath = Nothing
Set pic = Nothing
Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
MsgBox Err.Description, vbExclamation
Resume ExitProc
End Sub